# Exception through automation

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have a scenario like to generate Reports. When i do it manually, Click on the Report button system generates report, but through selenium automation system is displaying null exception something like this (which is not replicable through manual)

```
(TypeError) __gwt$exception: <skipped>: c is null
class com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException
Unknown.y$c(Unknown Source)
Unknown.sSd(Unknown Source)
```

How can i handle these kind of exceptions, is it a application problem or eclipse? Can someone suggest me on this

Comment: the exception is displayed in application not in eclipse.

Comment: Can you take a screenshot from the exception? Can you show the full exception trace from browsers inspector window?

Comment: so could you please share you code which causes this error?